# Check at most four check box and store checked value to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying some check boxes. The user can check a maximum of 4 boxes. I store the checked value in 4 textboxes.

My problem: **How can I correctly store the "new" checked value when the user randomly unchecks one box and checks another?**

I store values as follows: First checked into item_1, second checked into item_2, third checked into item_3 ... If the user unchecks the first checked box, for example, how can I store the value of the next box he or she checks into item_1? Please help.

Simplified code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_1" id="prodname_1"value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_2" id="prodname_2"value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_3" id="prodname_3"value="3"/>
.
.
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_10" id="prodname_10"value="10"/>

<input type="text" name="item_0" id="item_0"value=""/>
<input type="text" name="item_1" id="item_1"value=""/>
<input type="text" name="item_2" id="item_2"value=""/>
<input type="text" name="item_3" id="item_3"value=""/>


$(document).ready(function (e) 
{
    counter=0;
    $('input[id^="prodname_"]').change(function() 
     {
            id = $(this).attr('id');

            var arr = id.split('_');
            valueChecked=$('#'+id).val();
            if(this.checked)
            {
                if(counter==4)
                {
                    alert('Allready checked 4 items');
                    this.checked=false;
                    return false;
                }
                $("#item_"+counter).val(valueChecked);
                ++counter;
            }

    });
});
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie please check that when i randomly check uncheck text box does not contain proper value

Comment: Do you mind the gaps that unchecking can leave, or would you prefer the values to move up and fill the first items only?

Comment: Added a version 2 to my answer, that fills the items in order. Gives a cleaner result: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tmLnbvv0/10/

Comment: suppose at last when 1st 3rd 4th checlboxes are checked then i want 1,3,4 in text boxes

Comment: That is what the new versions do: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tmLnbvv0/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of retaining a counter, just count the number of checked boxes when the change occurs.

Revised to use the logic you intended (took a little while to figure that out) :)

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tmLnbvv0/9/

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var $items = $('input[id^="item_"]');
    var checkboxes = $('input[id ^= "prodname_"]').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var arr = id.split('_');
        valueChecked = $(this).val();

        // Count of checked checkboxes
        var counter = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // count the checked checkboxes
            if (counter > 4) {
                alert('Already checked 4 items');
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                // Add to the first available slot
                $items.filter(function(){return $(this).val() == ""}).first().val(valueChecked);
            }
        } else {
            // Remove the matching value
            $items.filter(function(){return $(this).val() == valueChecked;}).first().val('');
        }
    });
});
```

note: The "jQuery way" for changing checkboxes is to use `prop('checked', booleanvalue)` (also changed above)

**V2 - If you don't want gaps:**

This version is actually simpler as it just clears the items and fills them, in order, with any *checked* checkbox values.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/tmLnbvv0/13/

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var $items = $('input[id^="item_"]');
    var $checkboxes = $('input[id ^= "prodname_"]').change(function () {
        // Count of checked checkboxes
        var counter = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;

        // count the checked checkboxes
        if (counter > 4) {
            alert('Already checked 4 items');
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }

        // Clear all the items
        $items.val('');

        // Fill the items with the selected values
        var item = 0;
        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
            $('#item_' + (item++)).val($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: but i also want to store checked values to input box

Comment: Fixed and added 2 variations for you. The second one is *cleaner* (does not leave gaps) and the code is simpler too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var counter = 0,
    $items = $('input[name^="item_"]');
  $('input[id^="prodname_"]').change(function() {
    var id = this;

    if (this.checked) {
      if (counter == 4) {
        this.checked = false;
        return;
      }
      $("#item_" + counter).val(this.value).attr('data-value', this.value);
      ++counter;
    } else {
      var $item = $items.filter('[data-value="' + this.value + '"]');
      var index = $items.index($item);
      $items.slice(index, counter).each(function(i) {
        var $n = $items.eq(index + i + 1);
        $(this).val($n.val() || '').attr('data-value', $n.attr('data-value'));
      });
      counter--;
      $("#item_" + counter).val('').removeAttr('data-value');
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_1" id="prodname_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_2" id="prodname_2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_3" id="prodname_3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_4" id="prodname_4" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_5" id="prodname_5" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_6" id="prodname_6" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_7" id="prodname_7" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_8" id="prodname_8" value="8" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_9" id="prodname_9" value="9" />
<input type="checkbox" name="prodname_10" id="prodname_10" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="item_0" id="item_0" value="" />
<input type="text" name="item_1" id="item_1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="item_2" id="item_2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="item_3" id="item_3" value="" />
```

Comment: Unchecking them does not remove the matching item.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie missed to copy a variable definition... fixed